# Refresh page after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have two pages, on the first page you can select an item with a `<select> </select>`. When you select an item, a form is automatically displayed through an AJAX Call. In this form, data is automatically loaded from a mysql db in a `<textarea> </textarea>`. The moment you submit your form, I want the new data to be added to the `<textarea> </textarea>` I just can't manage this, who can help me?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnAdd").click(function (e) {
            /* Retrieving value from textboxes */
        var besproken = $('#besproken').val();  
            $.post("save.php", { 
              besproken: besproken, 
          }, function (data) {
          $("#autoSave").html("Coaching ");
          $("#btnAdd").attr("disabled", true);
          });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: So what part of this exactly is giving you trouble?  What are the current results and how does that differ from what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is insert the data into the textarea just use jQuery to selected the element `$("textarea")` then call the text method and pass in your data `.text(data)`. The result call will look like `$("textarea").text(data)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnAdd").click(function(e) {
    /* Retrieving value from textboxes */
    var besproken = $('#besproken').val();
    $.post("save.php", {
      besproken: besproken,
    }, function(data) {
      $("#autoSave").html("Coaching ");
      $("#btnAdd").attr("disabled", true);
      $("textarea").text(data);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a div. When you click submit you will get a ajax response, load this inside the div.

```
success: function(data){
     $("#status").load("url of the php-file");
     or 
     $("#status").html(data);
 }
```